# How would I go about strengthening protection of my .swf file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm still a beginning in flash in general and I'm attempting to strengthen the protection of my .swf file.

One of the ideas I had was to split the .swf file up, to so speak; creating a new swf with sensitive, but vital functions and values, storing it on my webserver, and having the launcher request the files after passing a few verification processes. Only flaw in this idea, is I have no idea how to add a class (if that's the right term?) to my project. I reversed another .swf file which included the same method using Base64 encryption, but I'm not too sure how to add an external .as file to execute in my project.

Of course, I've also found additional methods, such as using DCOMSoft SWF Protector (which wouldn't do much good) and obfuscation programs (which, too, can be reversed). I've recently found out about a .SWC called AS3Crypto, which I have no idea how to use. I've added the file to my AS3 Properties, but that's as far as I have gotten. The rest of AS3Crypto and its mysteries remain vague to me, and I am unable to find any useful information via Google.

I would really like to split the .swf into parts having them in different areas to make it more difficult to reverse, but I am not too sure how effective that would be, let alone how to actually do it. In regards to the external class (terminology?), since I was unable to find how to implement it with my project, I thought of salvaging the functions from the reversed .swf I have found and adding them into my internal script. Even then, the package begins with `public class $Base64 extends Object` -- `extends`I assume simply adds additional functionality to objects, but I do not believe this is entirely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if someone is committed enough, they will decrypt and piece together the information.  I understand your mission, I had the same feeling when I started AS3.

The most common ways to protect swf are:

1. Obfuscation - good against casual decompilers/hackers.
2. Shells like mochi - useless against decompilers, but ok if it adds obfuscation too.
3. Server side code - BEST PROTECTION available, but its still not perfect, it slows your swf file down and requires internet access to use the swf.

If you are serious about protecting your code, you must do it server side.

Comment: I have no problem making it server-side :) I thought about making it further secure by having a launcher request the actual .swf file, which would in turn request functions that would request other functions from my webserver. Inception. How would I go about adding an external AS3 script to my project?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to protect your swf that no body may able to de compile it and view your ActionScript Coding, then you should encrypt your swf with swf encryption tool like Amayeta SWF Encrypt. You can have a look at http://www.amayeta.com/ and get some useful details.

Thanks.

Comment: That tool can easily be bypassed by a decrypter via a simple Google search :/

Answer (score 0):

you can  Protect Your ActionScript Code Using **AS3 Obfuscator**

AS3Obfuscator is an application that lets you obfuscate your ActionScript source code, making it difficult to read when decompiled.

You can see an example [here](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/quick-tip-protect-your-actionscript-code-using-as3obfuscator/)

Don't forget you can **Lock Your SWF to a Specific Domain Name**

```
function pageDomainCheckInit(event:Event):void {
    if (url != "http://www.domainName.com/siteFolder/sitePage.html") {

        warning_txt.text="This file is running on the wrong URL. Content Access Restricted!";
        closeBoxTop.x = 0
        closeBoxTop.visible = true;
        closeBoxTop.height= stage.stageHeight/2
        Tweener.addTween(closeBoxTop,{width:stage.stageWidth, alpha: 0.8, time:1, transition:"easeInOutExpo"});

        closeBoxBottom.x = stage.stageWidth
        closeBoxBottom.visible = true;
        closeBoxBottom.height= stage.stageHeight/2
        Tweener.addTween(closeBoxBottom,{width:stage.stageWidth, time:1, alpha: 0.8, transition:"easeInOutExpo"});
    } else {

        warning_txt.text=" ";
        closeBoxTop.visible = false;
        closeBoxBottom.visible = false;
    }
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, pageDomainCheckInit);
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, pageDomainCheckInit);
```

For more information click [here](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-lock-your-swf-to-a-specific-domain-name/)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you should do when creating flash files (or other clientside files like xml etc) is make it as dumb as possible. 
Don't store passwords, id's, guids or important data in it, but create a server-side service/API which delivers all the data to the flash/client based on user input. It is easier to make a secure API than creating protected SWF-files.

It is also a good idea to monitor your own project http traffic using 'charles proxy' or fiddler (there are also firefox/chrome plugins for that). Look how data is transferred and if it is predictable and if it is easy to manipulate.

Btw, If you want to obfuscate anyway, I know a cool obfuscation trick: It is possible to embed the swf in a swf as bytearray. Create a new flashproject and mark this class as Main-document. Place the orginal .swf file inside the project. Make sure to set the document settings (stage size etc) the same as the input SWF.

```
    package 
    {
        import flash.display.Loader;
        import flash.display.Sprite;

        /**
         * @author Mark Knol
         */
        public class ByteArrayLoader extends Sprite
        {
            [Embed(source='../swf/myFlashFile.swf', mimeType='application/octet-stream')]
            private static const bytes:Class;

            public function ByteArrayLoader()
            {
                Loader( addChild( new Loader() ) ).loadBytes( new bytes() );
            }
        }
    }
```